# How to copy/display SQL query results as JSON in JetBrains DataGrip

Tags: sql, json, formatting, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

How to copy or display SQL query results as JSON in JetBrains DataGrip?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can select to display as JSON here:

[image: Select as JSON in Datagrip]